# Null Pointer Exception near actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false), during implementation of View Pager TabView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

Getting Null Pointer Exception near actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false), I have also implemented View Pager and Tabs.

I have have not defined @android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar in the manifest file.
When I don't implement TabView and View Pager and pass a normal activity then the app works but when I try to implement TabView and View Pager I getting Null Pointer Exception.

Can anyone point out the mistake which I would have done?

```
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Merchants", "Personal Payee" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_screen_tab_layout_bp);

    //Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    //Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
        .setTabListener(this));
    }

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}




@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}




@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu); //inflate our menu
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.item_refresh) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainScreenTab.this,ListMerchantType.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }
    else if (id == R.id.item_save) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainScreenTab.this,ListPayee.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
```

Comment: extend `ActionBarActivity` instead of `Activity`

Comment: I have not extended activity instead I have extended FragmentActivity which implements
ActionBar.TabListener

Answer (score 0):

> ActionBarCompat contains one Activity class which all of your Activity
>   classes should extend: ActionBarActivity. This class itself extends
>   from FragmentActivity so you can continue to use Fragments in your
>   application. There is not a ActionBarCompat Fragment class that you
>   need to extend, so you should continue using
>   android.support.v4.Fragment as the base class for your Fragments.

You have the info here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

That's the reason why you are getting NPE on `actionBar` element. So you should have it this way:

```
public class YourActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements TabListener {
```